# Sudo apt-get update error (ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: apt, updates

Hello Fellow Ubuntu users,

```
 sudo apt-get update
```

on ubuntu 14.04 it keeps saying:

```
E: Malformed line 10 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list (type)
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

Please help me it has been like this for a while now and I just found this website. Thanks!

Comment: @FranciscoLedesma, please add the tenth line of `/etc/apt/sources.list` (it's the output of `head -n 10 /etc/apt/sources.list | tail -n 1`) to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You could just delete the sources.list file, and then push settings and then enter software update, and hatch the upper option in the first line, and then close and reload and the malfunction is gone.

Answer (score 0):

Edit, as `root`, with the editor of your choice, the `/etc/apt/sources.list` file, and delete (or comment by placing `#` at the beginning of the line) the offending line (`line 10`).

One way to comment line 10 uses `sed` (read `man sed`):

```
sudo sed -i~ -e '10s/^/#/' /etc/apt/sources.list
```

This leaves a backup copy in `/etc/apt/sources.list~`